# Replace string that do not contain any digit, whitespace and parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to eliminate all the digit, whitespace and parenthesis in the column of dataframe.
So, I wrote the following code.

```
df_energy['Country'].replace(r'\d* \(.*\)','',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

However, it only eliminate whitespace and parenthesis.

```
{'China2',''China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region3'}
```

Items with digit at the end still remains the same.
May I know which part of the statement I miswrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex specifically looks for the pattern:

[image]

meaning that an input like `1 (string)` would match.

If you want to eliminate the charactes in the input regardless of order, I would suggest something like a simple list of characters to look for: `r'[\d ()]+'`

[image]

The screenshots come from CyrilEx https://extendsclass.com/ that can visualize regex and help you debug patterns